# Display routing table of router

Tags: router, routing

I have a Linksys E1200. Is there anyway to display the routing table of the router from my local box (windows 7)? I tried to look in the web interface but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

No way unless you flash it to DD-WRT, you can then `ssh` into it and do a `ip route` to see it.